# Can anybody help me pinpoint whats causing this error? SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot using discord.js, node.js, and npm. I am getting this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. I am a bit of an idiot so I can't really tell whats giving me this syntax error, or in better terms, where this error is occuring.

```js
// a is funny letter haha laugh
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
// epicly loads main commands like an epic
require('./core/loadWidgetListeners')(client);
// verify login thats kinda epic tho ngl
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})
// not epic function makes me not feel epic ): UnU
function hasUpperCase(str) {
    return (/[A-Z]/.test(str) // EPIC FUNCTION EPIC
}
// epic ping pong teehee
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "ping") {
    if (hasUpperCase(msg.content)) {
        msg.reply("pong! (screw you for using uppercase characters in that command)")
    } else {
        msg.reply("pong!")
    }
  }
})
// haha funny message aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aSd ASADSdaS
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "snoopdoguhohstinky") {
    msg.channel.send("n o")
  }
})
// logging code makes me EA SPORTS
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is active.`);
})
// hack my bot, i dare you.
client.login("CENSORED FOR OBVIOUS REASONS")
```

js makes me feel like a total dunce

Comment: Your `hasUpperCase()` function is missing a `)` - that's the kind of thing that any good IDE or programming editor would make pretty obvious.

Comment: i am a complete and total moron lmao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line is missing a closing parenthesis.

```
return (/[A-Z]/.test(str) // EPIC FUNCTION EPIC
```

Comment: Oh my god why did notepad say i have 26 matches for both

Comment: either way the error is still popping up and it is still referring to the character }

Comment: You added the `)` and it's still throwing the error?

Comment: @madladzen You're not getting a line number in the console?

Comment: nvm it isnt showing up anymore, i am slowly starting to dislike js because of this, first it was saying my code was correct but not changing my bots status and now its saying i have a unexpected } when its an unexpected )

Comment: I have no idea why it continued after another restart than after another started working though thats also really annoying

Comment: Probably a caching issue.  Anyway, the error is not wrong.  It doesn't know how much more stuff you're going to write inside those parentheses, but it knows there shouldn't be a closing curly brace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210086/discussion-between-madladzen-and-thingevery).